# Internal load balancer instances model

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I have the following set up:

- **public network**
  This network has internet access as the route tables routes the external traffic to a IGW
  I am deploying a small sample app **webAppPublic** in this network
- **private network A** - no internet access
- **private network B** - no internet access

**Note network A and network B are in two different AZs**

In private **network A** **and network B** I deployed a small sample app **webAppPrivate** used by **webAppPublic**
so one instance per network.

I am using a internal load balancer for **webAppPrivate**
I linked the load balancer to **network A and network B** and put the two instances as target group.

**webAppPublic** uses the dns name of the load balancer to communicate to **webAppPrivate**

This configuration works fine:
Furthermore I see in the console that if I call `dig  load-balancer-dns`
it resolves to two IP addresses for each subnetwork namely **private network A  and private network B**
So now I also have two load balancers node for each private network.

I also note that if I call dig multiple times I see the the order of the addresses changes so I guess AWS does this for dns load balancing
among the load balancers instances on the network A and B

I asked my self the question, what should happen if I remove one instance of **webAppPrivate** ?
In this case one of the load balancer would not find a instance in the same network and AZ to forward the request
to, so most likely the request will fail.

However after doing this I notice the work balancing still works fine, as I don't get any issues and the one instance remaining is always reached.

I am not sure how this happens, if the DNS query resolves the dns name to the load balancer instance in the
network and AZ from which I remove the instance I would expect this request to fail.

One possible explaination is that the instance of load balancer will, in case no instances are up and or healthy in its own network, contact AWS load balancer service elsewhere / or possibly the other instances of the laod balancer in different networks, before routing the actual traffic.
So the node of load balancer in one cannot network cannot take the routing decision on its own ?

I think my mental model about internal load balancing and private network is somewhat wrong, can you help me understand what happens here ?

Comment: Which type of AWS load balancer? Note that cross-zone load balancing is always turned on for ALB. See https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elb-dns-cross-zone-balance-configuration and other AWS docs on cross-zone load balancing.

Comment: ALB, and it should not be cross zone as I did not enable it.I think my "theory" would make sense even if cross zone is not enabled.  I am basically looking for some docs explaining what I am seeing.

Comment: Cross-zone load balancing is the ALB default and, afaik, was actually the only option available to users [until November 2022](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/application-load-balancers-turning-off-cross-zone-load-balancing-per-target-group/).

Comment: Ahh interesting, I just disable it for the target group, but still see the same behaviour. Was your expectations to see some requests fail to be forwarded ?

Comment: UPDATE: after disabling cross zone, the load balancer DNS only returns the IP of the load balancer node on the network on which there is the remaining active instance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Application Load Balancer (ALB).

Cross-zone load balancing is the default configuration for ALB. That means that each load balancer node distributes traffic across the registered targets in all enabled Availability Zones. When cross-zone load balancing is disabled, each load balancer node distributes traffic only across the registered targets within the same AZ as the load balancer is deployed.

As of late 2022, you can now [disable cross-zone load balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/disable-cross-zone.html).

See more at the cross-zone load balancing section of [How Elastic Load Balancing works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html).